# Questions about proving limits

Tags: calculus, limits

This is a question I found in an old test.
I can't seem to prove them:

1. Proving that: $$\lim_{x→0}{ln|x|} =-∞‎$$
2. Is it true that: $$\lim_{x→3}{\frac{1}{x-3}}=\infty‎$$

Comment: Well, what do you know about the logarithm function as the argument approaches zero? What do you know about $1/(x-3)$ as $x$ approaches 3?

Comment: The lecturer never touched logarithms in my course, so I don't know anything about limits with logarithms.

Comment: Then maybe a better question would be, "tell me enough about logarithms, starting from scratch, so that I can work out $\lim_{x\to0}\log|x|$." But even better would be to get a calculus textbook that does logarithms, and read up on it.

Answer (score 1):

Proof of 1:

We know that:

$$\lim_{x\to0}{ln|x|} =-\infty$$

So:

$$\lim_{x→0}{|x|}= e^{-\infty} = \frac{1}{e^\infty} = 0 $$